# Ubuntu 22.04 freeze at boot and sleep/suspend

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, 22.04, bug-reporting

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Dell Latitude 7480 laptop. But the system is acking strange. I will try to iterate through the processes I've done.

**Problem 1**

When I tried to do a normal installation, the screen went black after the Dell/Ubuntu logo and it never reached the installation page.
Retried to do the installation using safe graphics which resulted in a successful installation.
When I booted into the login after the first installation, the computer froze at the login screen. I could not move the cursor or do any keyboard commands. All that I was able to do was turn the keyboard backlight on and of.

After doing some research I encountered the "nomodeset" parameter, which enabled me to proceed to with the login and the computer acted "normal". I look through all settings to see if everything was normal. To which I discovered that the Graphics Card is not recognized or in settings/about/ is says: **"llvmpipe(LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits)"** to my understanding is a default fallback driver Ubuntu uses if the driver is not recognized?
or due to the system being booted with nomodeset?

Recognizing that the problem might be the graphic card, I tried to search for updates or different drivers in order to "provoke" the system to recognize the graphic card, without any success.

But when I booted the computer with an external monitor connected, the system booted fine without the "nomodeset" parameter, and the graphic card was recognizable. Meaning **"llvmpipe(LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits)"** changed to **INTEL HD GRAPHICS 620**. Booting with the external monitor and then removing it makes the system freeze and I need to press the power button to restart.

So the current situation is:

- If I'm using just the laptop I need to boot with nomodeset in order to use it.
- If I'm using an external monitor I can boot normally.

With the "external monitor method" I figure that I could maybe re-install ubuntu the normal way. Which I was able to do, though the problem remained after the completed normal installation.

**Problem 2**

When I tried to solve problem 1, I noticed that I'm unable to wake the computer after it has gone to "sleep" or is suspended. To solve it I need to reboot the system. Is this due to the graphic card? Or can both problems 1 and 2 be due to the same cause? I've seen some mention that the "unable to wake" is due to power settings.
This problem occurs both when having the external monitor connected and just using the laptop.

What I've tried is to update the system and look for any specific drivers, I've tried to downgrade the kernel and install ubuntu 20.04, all without any success.

**My specs are:**

**Processor:** INTEL CORE I5-7300U 2.60 GHz x 4

**Graphic Card:** Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620(KBL gt2)

**Kernel:** 5.15.3-051803-generic

**SSD:** 128 GB + 240 GB external

**Windowing:** Wayland

Thanks in advance!

//New Ubuntu user.

Comment: 2 separate problems needs 2 separate questions.

Comment: Even though they might be related?

Comment: Yeah, I disagree completely.  These are clearly related issues.